# Why is this recursive function overwriting the values of the second call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

Sorry for the title, I'm not even sure how to phrase what is happening here.

I'm working on an expense tracking program in React that supports multiple currencies. The expenses being tracked can be nested arbitrarily deep in a JSON object.

```
entertainment: {
  _values: {
    USD: 23,
    AUD: 5,
  },
  'food & drink': {
    _values: {
      AUD: 83,
    },
    'local bar': {
      _values: {
        AUD: 28,
        USD: 2,
      },
    },
  },
  minigolf: {
    _values: {
      USD: 112,
    },
  }
}
```

An expense can have an amount stored directly in it, but it can also act as a 'parent' category to further detailed sub-expenses.

To display the total value of an expense I've written a pair of functions:
`sumValues(values)`
Sums up an array of `_values` objects (a value object is a key-value store of currency codes and integers)

`totalExpense(expense)`
Returns the total value of an expense. ie any `_values` it has, + the totalExpense of any children expenses.

I thought I'd written these as pure functions, but when calling `totalExpense()` recursively the first child of an expense returns the wrong total.

```
totalExpense(entertainment);
//-> Object { USD: 137, AUD: 116 }
```

OK

```
totalExpense(entertainment['food & drink']);
//-> Object { AUD: 111, USD: 2 }
```

OK

```
totalExpense(entertainment);
totalExpense(entertainment['food & drink']);
//-> Object { AUD: 139, USD: 4 }
```

## NOT OK

I've been poking at this code for hours now, but for the life of me can't see what is happening:

```
  sumValues = values => {
    return values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      for (const currency in cur) {
        acc[currency]
          ? (acc[currency] = acc[currency] + cur[currency])
          : (acc[currency] = cur[currency]);
      }
      return acc;
    });
  };
```

```
  totalExpense = expense => {
    const values = [];

    if (expense['_values']) {
      values.push(expense['_values']);
    }

    const subExpenses = Object.keys(expense).filter(child => {
      return child[0] !== '_';
    });

    if (subExpenses.length > 0) {
      for (const subExpense of subExpenses) {
        let subtotal = this.totalExpense(expense[subExpense]);
        values.push(subtotal);
      }
    }

    if (values.length) {
      return this.sumValues(values);
    } else {
      throw Error('No values in this expense');
    }
  };
```

```
  render() {
    const entertainment = {
      _values: {
        USD: 23,
        AUD: 5,
      },
      'food & drink': {
        _values: {
          AUD: 83,
        },
        'local bar': {
          _values: {
            AUD: 28,
            USD: 2,
          },
        },
      },
      minigolf: {
        _values: {
          USD: 112,
        },
      },
    };

    console.log(this.totalExpense(entertainment));
    console.log(this.totalExpense(entertainment['food & drink']));
    console.log(this.totalExpense(entertainment['minigolf']));

    return;
  }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a _JSON Object_. JSON is _always_ a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `reduce` callback's initial value is the first item in the `values` array, and then you proceed to assign to that item:

```
    acc[currency]
      ? (acc[currency] = acc[currency] + cur[currency])
      : (acc[currency] = cur[currency]);
```

So, the first item gets mutated every time `sumValues` is called. Instead, provide an empty object as the initial value for the `reduce`:

```
 sumValues = values => {
    return values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      for (const currency in cur) {
        acc[currency]
          ? (acc[currency] = acc[currency] + cur[currency])
          : (acc[currency] = cur[currency]);
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
  };
```

```js
sumValues = values => {
  return values.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    for (const currency in cur) {
      acc[currency] ?
        (acc[currency] = acc[currency] + cur[currency]) :
        (acc[currency] = cur[currency]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};
totalExpense = expense => {
  const values = [];

  if (expense['_values']) {
    values.push(expense['_values']);
  }

  const subExpenses = Object.keys(expense).filter(child => {
    return child[0] !== '_';
  });

  if (subExpenses.length > 0) {
    for (const subExpense of subExpenses) {
      let subtotal = this.totalExpense(expense[subExpense]);
      values.push(subtotal);
    }
  }
  if (values.length) {
    return this.sumValues(values);
  } else {
    throw Error('No values in this expense');
  }
};
const entertainment = {
  _values: {
    USD: 23,
    AUD: 5,
  },
  'food & drink': {
    _values: {
      AUD: 83,
    },
    'local bar': {
      _values: {
        AUD: 28,
        USD: 2,
      },
    },
  },
  minigolf: {
    _values: {
      USD: 112,
    },
  },
};

console.log(totalExpense(entertainment));
console.log(totalExpense(entertainment['food & drink']));
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much.

I just assumed that it passed a copy of the initial value, not the value itself....